# Class method access to it's data members

Tags: c++, class, memory, stack, this

I would use a small code to explain my question:

```
class C {
    int a;
public:
    func() {
        a = 4;
    };
};

int main() {
    C obj1;
    obj1.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Here `func()` method tries to set `a`(a data member of `obj1`) to a value of 4. How does `func()` get access to `a`? Is it because `func()` has access to `this*` for `obj1`?
If that's true, how does `func()` get access to `this*`? Is it passed to `func()` as an implicit argument while calling `obj1.func()` from `main()`?
If it's passed as an argument, does `main()` stack consist of a `this*` stored as its local variable?
If no, how and when is the `this*` pointer generated and where is it stored?

I have tried to put across the question incrementally based on my understanding of the topic. If everything turns out to be true, I am confused whether for every object generated statically on the stack, an extra this* is stored on the stack.

Please feel free to suggest edits.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The C++ implicit this, and exactly how it is pushed on the stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297205/the-c-implicit-this-and-exactly-how-it-is-pushed-on-the-stack)

Comment: Member functions of a class automatically have access to the variables of the class. That's basic knowledge about classes.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, let me answer your questions.

> Here func() method tries to set a(a data member of obj1) to a value of
>   4. How does func() get access to 'a'? Is it because func() has access to this* for obj1?

Yes, your assumption is correct.

> If that's true, how does func() get access to this*? Is it passed to
>   func() as an implicit argument while calling obj1.func() from main?

I'll cover this more later in this reply, but yes. Every member function is passed an argument of self. The C++ compiler does this for you. Please note that static methods are an exception to this.

> If it's passed as an argument, does main() stack consist of a this*
>   stored as its local variable?  If no, how and when is the this*
>   pointer generated and where is it stored?

Take a look at the following examples. The first is in C and the second is in CPP.

```
struct A{
  int i;
}
increment(A* a){
 a->i +=1;
}

int main(){
  A anA; 
  anA.i = 0;
  increment(&anA);
}
```

Now, look at the following in cpp.

```
struct A{
   int i;

   public:
   void increment(){
     i+=1;
   }
}

int main(){
   A anA;
   anA.increment();
}
```

The examples above are, at a very basic nature, identical. They perform the same task and go about doing it in the same manner (excluding things like constructors/destructors). The main difference is that the cpp compiler takes care of passing a pointer to your model (struct A) to the function where in C you would need to pass it yourself.

`this*,` is really just a pointer to your struct. So in the example above its a pointer to `anA`.

I would suggest reading thinking in c++. It is free and one of the books that got me started with CPP. If you want to have a good understanding of the language its worth the time. [here](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html/).

Comment: Regarding the first comment of yours 'Yes, all member functions have access to class variables.'. That statement is made true because of the 'this*'. Had the pointer not being implicitely passed to the function, there would be nothing binding the function and the class variables together. Correct?  

Overall, your answer clears my doubt. Thanks :)