# Class static method access to it's static data members

Tags: c++, class, memory, static

This question is an extension to:
[Class method access to it's data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642805/class-method-access-to-its-data-members)
The take away from the question was that whenever a class method is called, it is implicitely passed the address of the object which helps it access the data members of the class using a 'this*'.

The follow up question is:

- How are the static methods of the class able to access the static data members of the class?

The argument remains the same. A function can only access the local variables loaded on the stack.

- Are the static data members or their address loaded onto the static function stack implicitely?
- If no, how does it work?

Comment: There's no such thing as "static function stack".  Class static members are just global variables that have a `::` in their name; they have an address assigned by the linker.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because both are not bound to an instance of that class.

For e.g.

```
class test
{
   public:
   static int i=5;
   static int getI(){return i;}
};
```

You can access `i` like:

```
int a=test::i;
```

or like

```
int a=test::getI();
```

`i` is stored in the global data part of the program. It is not bound to an object, therefore it is also identical for every instance created. You can access i without create an instance of `class test`. `class test` merely a namespace in this situation. There is no memory magic.